# c++ template member function error

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to C++ template. The following code is trying to get data vector of different type when different input type is given.

MS2013 gives some bizarre error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall data::get_data<int>(class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > &)const " (??$get_data@H@data@@QBEXAAV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

What's the problem? Is it incorrect to use the argument std::vector& to specify the template function?

New update:
I moved the member function definition out.
The function call in main function is also attached. The error is the same.

```
#include "data.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    data d1(2);
    std::vector<int32_t> ld;
    d1.get_data(ld);
    return 0;
}

class data {
private:
    std::vector<int16_t> sdata;     // container for 16-bit fixed point                   
    std::vector<int32_t> ldata;     // container for 32-bit fixed point  
    std::vector<char> cdata;        //   
    std::vector<float> fdata;       // container for 32-bit floating point                
    std::vector<double> ddata;      // container for 64-bit floating point
    int16_t dtype;
public:
    data(int16_t type) :sdata(10, 0), ldata(10, 1), cdata(10, 'c'), 
                        fdata(10, 2.0), ddata(10, 3.00),dtype(type){}
    template <typename T>
    void get_data(std::vector<T>& outdata) const;
};

template <typename T>
void data::get_data(std::vector<T>& outdata) const {
    switch (dtype) {
    case 1:
        outdata = sdata;
        break;
    case 2:
        outdata = ldata;
        break;
    case 3:
        outdata = cdata;
        break;
    case 4:
        outdata = fdata;
        break;
    case 5:
        outdata = ddata;
        break;
    default:
        std::cerr << "Unknown data format" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `data::` from your member function `get_data`.

Comment: That's a linker error, and you must have got a compilation error before that since you can't assign most of those members to a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: That is, the template has been instantiated as a member function `void data::get_data(std::vector<int>& outdata) const`, and that function doesn't pass the type checking.

Comment: It isn't clear how you arrived at a linker error. Your code cannot possibly compile. See a suitably simplified example [here](http://ideone.com/sOsTvz). Note the error `error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<double>' and 'const std::vector<char>')`.

Answer (score 1):

there need not template,you can this

```
class data {
private:
    std::vector<int16_t> sdata;     // container for 16-bit fixedpoint                   
    std::vector<int32_t> ldata;     // container for 32-bit fixed point  
    std::vector<char> cdata;        //   
    std::vector<float> fdata;       // container for 32-bit floating point                
    std::vector<double> ddata;      // container for 64-bit floating point
    int16_t dtype;
public:
    data(int16_t type) :sdata(10, 0), ldata(10, 1), cdata(10, 'c'), fdata(10, 2.0), ddata(10, 3.00),dtype(type)
    {

    }
    void get_data(std::vector<int16_t>& outdata)
    {   outdata = sdata;    }
    void get_data(std::vector<int32_t>& outdata)
    {   outdata = ldata;    }
    void get_data(std::vector<char>& outdata)
    {   outdata = cdata;    }
    void get_data(std::vector<float>& outdata)
    {   outdata = fdata;    }
    void get_data(std::vector<double>& outdata)
    {   outdata = ddata;    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    data d1(2);
    std::vector<int32_t> ld;
    d1.get_data(ld);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a **compile-time** construct at **run-time**. That isn't possible.
Look at the declaration:

```
void data::get_data(std::vector<T>& outdata) const
```

To be compiled and included in your program, the compiler would need to know **at compile time** the type of `T`.

But the type of `T` will be only known at **run-time**, because it is the value of the variable `dtype` that determines it inside the function, so at **run-time**.

What you really want is either a polymorphic class or a simple function.

Comment: I attached the main function code which called get_data(). The error is the same.

Comment: Of course. My point was not that declaring `main` will make it work, but make you understand why this template method can't compile. What is it that is not clear in my answer, I can reformulate if needed